# How do i do this code in a cleaner way without bugging?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-cloud-firestore, syntax-error

```
let db = firebase.firestore()

let batch = db.batch()

let whoTaggedRef = db.collection('posts').doc(postId).collection('whoTagged').doc(myId)

    if (type === 'objects') {
      batch.update(postTagsef, {
        'tags.objects': firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(tagName)
      })
    }
    if (type === 'animals') {
      batch.update(postTagsef, {
        'tags.animals': firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(tagName)
      })
    }
```

when i try to use something cleaner, firestore does not recognize.

let type = 'objects'
`tags.${type}`, lint runs a error,
when i try let tagRef = `tags.${type}` to put tagRef instead of 'tags.objects', firestore doesn't apply in data in the right manner, but, i have to always declare all possibilites in hand, this will add almost 40 lines of junk code...

How can i run properly?